# Несколько JQuery Slider на странице

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

Подскажите пожалуйста, подключил jqueryui.com/slider на страницу , задал свои настройки, все работает. Он у меня дублируется в трех местах, при копипасте в новом месте он уже не отображается. Подскажите как решить проблему без подключения дополнительных слайдеров? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider();
    $( "#slider2" ).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      value: 2,
    });
    $( "#slider3" ).slider();
     
     
    $( "#slider4, #slider5" ).slider();
      
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="slider1"></div>


<div id="slider2"></div>


<div id="slider3"></div>
  

<div id="slider4"></div>


<div id="slider5"></div>
  
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!